# Is it possible to programmatically force an iOS app in split view / slide over to go full screen in ios9?

Tags: ios, splitview, split-screen-multitasking

I'm implementing an app that needs a camera preview using AVCaptureSession. Unfortunately iOS9 will interrupt the AVCaptureSession as soon as Split View or Slide Over is on. The system allows to detect such an interruption (see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33086527/1896336).

The good thing is that we can warn the user to go Full Screen but I was actually wondering if we could programmatically set the app to go Full Screen when the user taps a "yes take me back to full screen" button ?

Comment: Doubt it.  This sounds like something Apple would control in the interest of the user

Answer (score -1, accepted):

No. If you don't like this behavior, don't use iPad Multitasking (opt out by insisting on full screen in the *Info.plist*).

Comment: This is well covered in the relevant WWDC 2015 video from Apple.

Comment: Ok matt thanks for the information. It's kind of sad tough as Apple's built-in Contacts app allows to take a picture in split view mode through UIImagePickerController. Well...